# Android - How to add bottom navigationbar in all activities

Tags: android, navigationbar, bottombar, android-navigation-bar

I have an application at present with main activity. i need to add navigationbar at bottom. am planning to have three things in this navigationbar (home, help, settings). now i have leaned to add navigationbar with fragments from http://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example/

but it works only with fragments. my need is that when i click home i need to go to MainActivity page and also this drawer should be there in all activities

Comment: I think the concept which you are missing is, you can use bottom navigation view in an activity and use 3 fragments home, help and settings. In such way you can still be on same activity and being on any page, bottom navigation you can see.

Comment: didn't get what u said

Answer (score 0):

Android Support Library `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'` has come up with the new `bottomnavigationview` which i think is what you need.

Refer to this link https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2016/10/29/android-bottomnavigationview-example/

It shows `bottomnavigationview` with three fragments. Properly read the whole blog and you can customize on your own as needed.

Comment: Original post states: "but it works only with fragments. my need is that when i click home i need to go to MainActivity page and also this drawer should be there in all activities". The blog link doesn't discuss 'activities' at all, just fragments.